# C++ добавление модуля к работающей части

Tags: c++, многопоточность, ipc

Есть здоровый проект на C++. Он компилируется, запускается. Далее. Можно ли как-то написать модуль (по-простому, другую прогу(поменьше, попроще)), который будет подключаться к данному проекту и работать с данными в работающем коде(т.е. вызывать функции, обращаться к классам, писать что-то куда-то), т.е. как не останавливая работу проекта, не меняя его исходники и не перекомпилируя подключить такой модуль?

Дополнительные детали: такие модули постепенно подключаются новые и новые, желательно, чтобы в проекте операции каждого такого модуля функционировали в отдельном потоке.

Прошу подсказать мне, что посмотреть на эту тему, да и вообще любые идеи будут полезны. Пока сам я дошел до создания доп процесса для каждого нового модуля и использования IPC, например shm + shared_mutex из boost::interprocess. Вопрос больше в том, как сделать, использую потоки, такое динамическое подключение нового кода, если вообще можно.

Небольшая добавка: можно обойтись упрощенно тем, что каждый модуль может только читать определнные данные других модулей, уже подключенных. И все. Ну и у него могут другие читать данные.

Обновление: реализация сделана в настоящее время под Win на основе динамической подгрузки dll. Таким образом приостанавливается и обновляется часть системы.

Comment: Система plugin'ов и внутренних API нужна.

Comment: Так а чем не подходящая текущая реализация с помощью DLL? Подкладываешь рядом в папку dll, даёшь основной программе сигнал что мол добавили модуль (либо сама основная программа время от времени обновляет список DLL), далее запускаем в отдельном потоке некую главную функцию DLL назовём её Main(), таже передаём в эту функцию например указатель на функцию через которую DLL может общаться с главным модулем, общение может происходить например за счёт обмена например JSON или ASN.1 закодированными командами и данными. Кстати под Линукс ведь тоже есть аналог DLL - .so файлы.

Comment: Да, реализация на dll всем устраивает, это рабочая версия, я просто написал здесь правку на свой неотвеченный вопрос, теперь его стали комментировать и я не пойму, как его откатить, чтобы никого не отвлекал.

Comment: @I.S.M.Если хотите удалить вопрос то под ним есть "удалить" рядом с "править" под тэгами. Но лучше если вы уже знаете как у вас решено в деталях, то лучше напишите ответ, ответ самому себе можно делать, в ответе опишите все детали как была решена задача. Вопрос хороший и развёрнутый ответ на него может пригодиться другим людям!